# Why components from JInternalFrame won't show properly?

Tags: java, swing

I don't know which the cause. But when I tried to go to my internal frame. It won't show me the complete JComponents inside of it. It just show the JTextfields, but when I hover the mouse in my components this is the time that only it shows the JComboBox. Any help why I encounter this problem? I used GUI builder on this frame.

[image: SC]

Structure of MainFrame.

[image]

Comment: Please write a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so we can understand what's wrong.

Comment: You are not 100% right! The ComboBox on the left is also **always** shown, not only the textboxes.